# Quit less when pipe closes

Tags: bash

As part of a bash script, I want to run a program repeatedly, and redirect the output to `less`. The program has an interactive element, so the goal is that when you exit the program via the window's X button, it is restarted via the script. This part works great, but when I use a pipe to `less`, the program does not automatically restart until I go to the console and press `q`. The relevant part of the script:

```
while :
do
    program | less
done
```

I want to make `less` quit itself when the pipe closes, so that the program restarts without any user intervention. (That way it behaves just as if the pipe was not there, except while the program is running you can consult the console to view the output of the current run.)

Alternative solutions to this problem are also welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of exiting `less`, could you simply aggregate the output of each run of `program`?

```
while :
do
    program
done | less
```

Having `less` exit when `program` would be at odds with one useful feature of `less`, which is that it can buffer the output of a program that exits before you finish reading its output.

---

UPDATE: Here's an attempt at using a background process to kill `less` when it is time. It assumes that the only program reading the output file is the `less` to kill.

```
while :
do
    ( program > /tmp/$$-program-output; kill $(lsof -Fp | cut -c2-) ) &
    less /tmp/$$-program-output
done
```

`program` writes its output to a file. Once it exits, the `kill` command uses `lsof` to
find out what process is reading the file, then kills it. Note that there is a race condition; `less` needs to start before `program` exists. If that's a problem, it can
probably be worked around, but I'll avoid cluttering the answer otherwise.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that if I run the program several times, it will accumulate quite a lot of output, so when I check the console the "relevant" information (for the latest run) is way down at the bottom. (Note that the feature of not scrolling is something I *want* which is part of the reason I am using `less` in the first place, but only on a per-run basis.) Also there is a potential memory problem with storing so many program outputs.

Comment: As for why I am using individual instances, the output of `program` is only relevant while the UI for `program` is open, and only for that particular run of the program (it's something like a compiler), so there is no need to cache or hold on to output from old runs. The while loop is just there so I don't have to run the program again, i.e. I am using the X button as a 'recompile' command. Do you think there is some solution along the lines of opening a subshell and killing the less process from another thread? I'm not skilled enough with bash scripting to do something like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am developing bash via the msysgit installation on windows, which apparently doesn't come with `lsof`. I'll close this question, but my "solution" is just to pipe the program output through an `awk` script that cuts down on the output, so that I don't need less.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to kill the process group `program` and `less` belong to instead of using `kill` and `lsof`.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'kill 0' EXIT

while :
do
   # script command gives sh -c own process group id (only sh -c cmd gets killed, not entire script!)
   # FreeBSD script command
   script -q /dev/null sh -c '(trap "kill -HUP -- -$$" EXIT; echo hello; sleep 5; echo world) | less -E -c'
   # GNU script command
   #script -q -c 'sh -c "(trap \"kill -HUP -- -$$\" EXIT; echo hello; sleep 5; echo world) | less -E -c"' /dev/null
   printf '\n%s\n\n' "you now may ctrl-c the program: $0" 1>&2
   sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with chepner's suggestion, if you *really* want individual `less` instances, I think this item for the man page will help you:

```
   -e or --quit-at-eof
          Causes less to automatically exit the second time it reaches end-of-file.  By  default,
          the only way to exit less is via the "q" command.

   -E or --QUIT-AT-EOF
          Causes less to automatically exit the first time it reaches end-of-file.
```

you would make this option visible to less in the `LESS` envir variable

```
export LESS="-E"
while : ; do
    program | less
done
```

IHTH

Comment: Using `less -e` was one option I investigated before posting. Instead of pressing `q`, I have to scroll to the bottom before it continues. `less -E` and `export LESS="-E"` appear to have the same effect.

Comment: what about `export LESS="-E+G"` ? Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately this causes less not to print anything, because it is waiting for the end of the file to arrive (which won't happen, since this is a pipe so the connection is held open).

Comment: Yes, weird, it displayed a complete file and then quit on one machine that I use at work But on another machine it was as you said, no output. Good luck.